# Can I avoid outdated byte-compiled elisp files?

Tags: byte-compilation

Occasionally, when I start Emacs, I get a message like.

> Source file `/home/USER/.emacs.d/elpa/....el' newer than byte-compiled file

Also, I sometimes edit a package I'm developing and forget to
recompile it. When I try to load the new file, it takes me a while to
realise that Emacs is still using the old compiled file.

**Is there a way I can tell Emacs to completely avoid byte-compiled files that are older than their respective source files?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Emacs 24.3 or below

There's no built-in way of preventing these old files from being loaded, but
there are easy ways to get rid of them.

- You can recompile the entire elpa directory by calling:
  `M-x byte-recompile-directory RET ~/.emacs.d/elpa/`.
  This should get rid of outdated files.
- You can use the
  [auto-compile](https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile) package and
  activate `auto-compile-on-load-mode` which can compile files before
  they are loaded.

### Emacs 24.4

Yes, and it turns out to be rather simple. The `load-prefer-newer`
variable serves precisely this purpose.

```
(setq load-prefer-newer t)
```

Unfortunately, it won't work when some code specifically targets the
`.elc` file, such as `(load "server.elc")`. But it should be enough as
long as you're using `require`s or calling `load` without a suffix, which you should.

From the doc:

> load-prefer-newer is a variable defined in lread.c.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means load prefers the newest version of a file.
>   This applies when a filename suffix is not explicitly specified and
>   load is trying various possible suffixes (see load-suffixes and
>   load-file-rep-suffixes).  Normally, it stops at the first file
>   that exists unless you explicitly specify one or the other.  If this
>   option is non-nil, it checks all suffixes and uses whichever file is
>   newest.
>   Note that if you customize this, obviously it will not affect files
>   that are loaded before your customizations are read!

Comment: I would urge people to use the (excellent!) [`auto-compile`](https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile) library in Emacs 24.4+, as well as below. It's a real configure-and-forget solution. `load-prefer-newer` only ensures that you'll *continue to run slow uncompiled code* after your compiled code gets out of date.

Comment: @phils Nowadays byte code isn't much faster than plain source code, thanks to eager macro expansion.

Comment: Changes I made to org-agenda-sorting-strategy (in org-agenda.el) weren't being reflected after a restart, but recompiling the .elc files as described in the answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 17):

If you only set `load-prefer-newer` (where available), the correct code will get loaded, but it might not have been byte-compiled, so there may be a slight performance penalty.

You can use Jonas Bernoulli's excellent [auto-compile](https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile) library to help make sure this problem doesn't arise. In particular, `auto-compile-on-load-mode` will recompile outdated `.elc` files before loading them.

Answer (score 3):

I met this on the Internet long time ago:

```
;; If you're saving an elisp file, likely the .elc is no longer valid:
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'esk-remove-elc-on-save)
(defun esk-remove-elc-on-save ()
  "If you're saving an elisp file, likely the .elc is no longer valid."
  (make-local-variable 'after-save-hook)
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook
            (lambda ()
              (if (file-exists-p (concat buffer-file-name "c"))
                  (delete-file (concat buffer-file-name "c"))))))
```

if you work with `FILE` in emacs-lisp-mode and you save it -- the code above removes `FILEc` if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

found a snippet similar to sanityinc's, works for current.

LesleyLai/recompile-on-save.el:
https://gist.github.com/LesleyLai/627085e275d2cf46429c0f44c27a92d7

```lisp
(defun recompile-elc-on-save ()
  "If you're saving an elisp file, likely the .elc is no longer valid."
  (make-local-variable 'after-save-hook)
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook
            (lambda ()
              (if (file-exists-p (byte-compile-dest-file buffer-file-name))
                  (byte-compile-file buffer-file-name)))))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'recompile-elc-on-save
          )
```

Comment: Please summarize what the snippet does. Otherwise, the is a link-only answer. Maybe just include the snippet (and keep the link, for attribution), if it is really just a "snippet".

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you taught me.

Comment: Thx! Much better.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I sometimes edit a package I'm developing and forget to recompile it. When I try to load the new file, it takes me a while to realise that Emacs is still using the old compiled file.

May I suggest to add a hook in your init file?

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'byte-compile-current-buffer)
```

Or, if you want to apply the hook only on el files:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'byte-compile-current-buffer nil t)))
```

Comment: Whoah, that would try to byte-compile even non-elisp buffers. Not ideal! The robust way to do this is with the auto-compile package.