# Problem with compiling PDF with ox-groff

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

`M-x org-groff-export-to-groff` works fine (exports `.groff` file for the org-file)

However, when I try to compile `pdf` from org-file with (`M-x org-groff-export-to-pdf`) following error show:

```
Saving file /home/garid/test.groff...
Wrote /home/garid/test.groff
Processing Groff file test.groff ...
shell-quote-argument: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

Could you explain what go wrong?

FYI, I added following configurations to my `init.el` for ox-groff.

```
(use-package org-contrib)
(require 'ox-groff)
```

[image]

Comment: `ox-groff` is buggy (that's why it's in the unsupported `org-contrib` package). Unfortunately, since there is no maintainer, there is no place to send a bug report. You will either have to fix it yourself (please submit any fixes you make by sending them to the Org mode mailing list: that way they will be available for everybody else), or ask at the Org mode mailing list, bearing in mind that it *IS* unsupported, so you may not get any response, or just use it to generate the `groff` file and then compile that by hand (I did the latter and it seems to work in a simple case).

Comment: BTW, the buggy function seems to be `org-groff-compile`. It uses a variable `out-dir` which is set to `nil` and then used in a call to `shell-quote-argument`; but `shell-quote-argument` cannot deal with a `nil` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with one change to the `ox-groff.el` file. Change line 1897 from this:

```el
     ...
     (out-dir (file-name-directory file))
     ...
```

to this:

```
     ...
     (out-dir (file-name-directory full-name))
     ...
```

In fact, the master branch of the repo you were pointed to in your other question ([https://git.sr.ht/~bzg/org-contrib](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib)) already contains this fix, in contrast to the 0.4 version of `org-contrib` that you get from the ELPA (nongnu) repository. So to that extent, my comment above was too pessimistic: things do get fixed (but it is still unsupported).

Comment: Thank you for your great response. Even after changing to `file` to `full-name`, I got same output

Comment: Did you reload the file after changing it? Or restart emacs? One way to check is to say `C-h f org-groff-compile` and then click on the link at the end of the first line, which will take you to the source code of the function; then scroll down and check that the line has indeed been changed. Once you are inside the function, you can do `C-M-x` to redefine the function, incorporating the change (assuming that it is present).

Comment: Yes I have have done `C-M-x` at the `org-groff-compile` function, close and re-open emacs. The result is same

Comment: Ah, Sorry, an update: when I start `emacs --daemon` I haven't noticed following lines: `Source file ‘/home/garid/.config/emacs/elpa/org-contrib-0.4/ox-groff.el’ newer than byte-compiled file; using older file` So `emacs` seems using the unchanged version of `ox-groff`

Comment: an Update; finally done it. According to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/185/can-i-avoid-outdated-byte-compiled-elisp-files). With this line `(setq load-prefer-newer t)` added, my emacs uses newly changed `ox-groff-compile`, and it produces PDF as expected. Thank you